# Gatsby: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, gatsby, contentful

I get this error in my Gatsby app that pulls places data for Author. the error shows when map() points of author.social is null

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`

I already tried to give a default value, but its seems not working

This is the default code :

```
authors: ({ node: author }) => {
    return {
      ...author,
      social: author.social.map(s => ({ url: s })),
    };
  },
```

This is the my change :

```
authors: ({ node: author }) => {
      return {
        ...author,
        social: author.social.map(s => {
          if (s === null) {
            return ({ url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com' });
          } else {
            return ({ url: s });
          }
        })
        ,
      };
    },
```

Any help would be very helpful,

Thanks

Comment: You could `console.log(author)` before the return to inspect what you really have in this `author` variable. And I think you should be checking if the variable is null or emplty before applying map to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I would do:

```
authors: ({ node: author }) => {
    // This to inspect what there is inside the variable 
    console.log(author);
    // And something like this to avoid the error:
    if(author.social && author.social.length > 0){
      // code here
    }
  });
```

Comment: Mmm... ok, true, I'm updating the answer, thanks :-)
What you put in that `if` @Studentofcode depends of what is the response you are getting